# Do I need to pay tax in US that ESPPS and RSUs earned in India

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, espp

When I was working in India I got some RSUs and also purchased ESPPs from my company by contributing from my salary.Its US based company located in India. I have an account in ETrade.

ETrade has deducted 30% of RSUs as part of taxes before it vests in my ETrade account and the ESPPs I purchased from my salary which is already a taxable income in India.

I got H1-B,moved to US and I resigned my Indian company.

So,My question is do I need to pay tax in US if I sell shares being in US.I have paid taxes for all my RSUs and ESPPs, while I was in India.

Please let me know your thoughts on this,Your is greatly appreciated.